# Which "iPhone developer program" to choose?

Tags: iphone, iphone-developer-program

This question might sound silly for some of you...

I work in a company that among other things develop apps for iPhone.
I am the only iPhone developer on this company (for the moment).
Which "iPhone developer program" should we choose? company or individual?

If we choose "company", then what we need to do is to pay the 99$ fee for the "company program" and start develop? or should we need to buy the "company program", and buy another "individual program" for each future developer?

How is this thing works?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which "iPhone developer program"
>   should we choose? company or
>   individual?

If you're developing apps for your company, choose the company option. You'll need to supply some documentation to show that the company is an actual business (DUNS number, possibly a business license, stuff like that.)

> If we choose "company", then what we
>   need to do is to pay the 99$ fee for
>   the "company program" and start
>   develop?

Yes.

> or should we need to buy the
>   "company program", and buy another
>   "individual program" for each future
>   developer?

No. The differences between the company and individual options are that the company option lets you have multiple developers on the same development team, and you have to provide the documentation that you're an actual business. The individual option allows only a single developer, but you don't have to have as much documentation. Since you're developing for your company, your company will want to be able to have multiple developers, and they'll want the apps you develop to remain under their control even if you leave the company.